# jQuery Mobile and Form Submission

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have decided to jump into the jQuery Mobile framework for a Wordpress enabled mobile theme.

I am now running into the issue of submitting forms with the hash tag in the url and trying to do validation and ajax posting.  Basically it does not work.

ex: website.com/contact/ <- works
website.com/#/contact/ <- does not work

I am aware of the rel="external" tag for href's which eliminate the # from the url.  But I have blog posts with a custom plugin that renders sign up forms that I will not be able to use the rel="external" for.  I guess I could use it for all links but that would eliminate the smooth transitions.

What are my options to try and get this to work?  I am trying to bind the .submit to the form, do some validation and then ajax post it.

Update--

```
<form id="myform" action="myfile.php" method="post">
<input type="text" id="mytext" name="mytext" />
<input type="submit" id="myform_submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and my script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
 jQuery("#contact_submit").submit(function(){
        alert('WTF');
        }); 
 });
```

Changed that to:

```
<form id="myform" action="myfile.php" method="post">
<input type="text" id="mytext" name="mytext" />
<input type="button" id="myform_submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and my script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
 jQuery("#contact_submit").click(function(){
        alert('WTF');
        }); 
 });
```

Both do not work with the # in the url.

I also added this BEFORE the jquery.mobile.js file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).bind(
   "mobileinit", function(){
   jQuery.extend( jQuery.mobile, { ajaxFormsEnabled: false });
   });
</script>
```

Still no go.

(FYI the jQuery instead of $ is because of WordPress)

--another update.

Since I am using Wordpress some of the functions are acting weird.  Like is_home().  No matter what 'page' I am on the function comes back as true.  I think this has to do with the ajax calls for each page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch off AJAX wrapping. Read here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/#docs/api/globalconfig.html

Also - I've seen something about problems with slashes, but now I can't find it, so be sure to use alpha3 version of JQM

[edit]

This was mentioned a few times before - in some other threads. If you go to a page and JQM loads it with AJAX, then only `body` is taken AND NO document.ready fires, as the dom is ready already ;) (I'm quoting myself here)

Comment: Not sure if that is it.  I changed <input type="submit" /> to <input type="button" /> and added a click handler with just an alert.  No go with the # in the url.  Without it is money.

Comment: Don't try messing with the form. Disabling AJAX should work. You can try experimenting with versions - compare jqm alpha2 and alpha3 working with that (caution: alpha2 had different settings)

Comment: Hmm.  I might wait to use jQuery until a few more release.  I disabled the AJAX but still no luck.  It works fine without the # in the url.  Once that is in there no go.  I am assuming this is a security thing built into the web browser. :(

Comment: Read my edit. It has nothing to do with disabling. I guess you even disable it in the wrong place. To put it short: javascript will work only in the first page you load.

Comment: Cool, sorta figured that.  Going to try and do rel="external" on some of that pages but kinda blows for the pages I cannot.

Comment: I've tried turning off ajax globally, doesn't work at all, still uses it

Comment: Please note that this answer was provided for alpha3 and might not be relevant anymore. Can you describe what you did in more detail?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not entirely sure where you are calling your `jQuery.ready` function but the recommended way to register handlers is by binding to the `pagecreate` event for your specific pages. The `pagecreate` events should be handled by `jQuery.ready` in the first page only. I recently built a site using jQuery mobile and I ran into exactly this problem. The following code should get you where you want to be:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#id_of_page").live('pagecreate', function() {
        $("form").submit(function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();

            // Do stuff here (usually AJAX);

            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, I didn't experiment enough to determine if all of that is necessary. I do know that this did the trick for me. I almost instincively add the `return false` to all of my form submits that are handled by AJAX. Hope this help!

Comment: FYI: probably want `pageinit` instead of `pagecreate` now (http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/events.html)